# STATIC_ROOT vs STATIC_URL in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls, django-staticfiles

I am confused by `static root` and want to clarify things.

To serve static files in Django, the following should be in `settings.py` and `urls.py`:

```
import os
PROJECT_DIR=os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

## 1. Absolute path to the directory in which static files should be collected

```
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static_media/')
```

## 2. URL prefix for static files

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

## 3. Additional locations for static files

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'static/'),)
```

...and in `urls.py` the following lines:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += patterns('', (
    r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$',
    'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}
))
```

## 4. We also use `python manage.py collectstatic`

Questions:

1. Could anyone please explain the workflow to me: how should things ideally be done. As of now, I copy/paste the above code snippets into their designated locations and continue making new files in the static directory and it works. In my `settings.STATIC_ROOT`, however, I have pointed to a different directory.
2. It would be great if someone could explain the workflow of each setting: how files are collected and managed, and what would be a good practice to follow.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify on what you mean by 'explain the workflow'?  also your url patterns should be conditional on if you are developing in part 3. you can do this by adding `if settings.DEBUG:` django is not very good at serving static media, this should be left to a real webserver.

Comment: Hi @user993563 i cant even find the solution in several forum what i want. but your questions explain it clearly thanks man... great job...

Comment: Good Explanation, Thanks

Answer (score 113):

### STATIC_ROOT

> The absolute path to the directory where `./manage.py collectstatic` will collect static files for deployment.
>   **Example: `STATIC_ROOT="/var/www/example.com/static/"`**

now the command `./manage.py collectstatic` will copy all the static files(ie in static folder in your apps, static files in all paths) to the directory `/var/www/example.com/static/`. now you only need to serve this directory on apache or nginx..etc.

### STATIC_URL

> The `URL` of which the static files in `STATIC_ROOT` directory are served(by Apache or nginx..etc).
>   **Example: `/static/` or `http://static.example.com/`**

If you set `STATIC_URL = 'http://static.example.com/'`, then you must serve the `STATIC_ROOT` folder (ie `"/var/www/example.com/static/"`) by apache or nginx  at url `'http://static.example.com/'`(so that you can refer the static file `'/var/www/example.com/static/jquery.js'` with `'http://static.example.com/jquery.js'`)

Now in your django-templates, you can refer it by:

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static "jquery.js" %}"></script>
```

which will render:

```
<script src="http://static.example.com/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Whats the dfference between your example and this: href="{% static "jquery.js" %}"

Comment: @macdonjo both `{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery.js` and `{% static "jquery.js" %}` are same. ie both will return `/static/jquery.js`. [Newer django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) versions recommend to use `{% static "jquery.js" %}`, but you need to load the templatetag, ie `{% load staticfiles %}`. in [older django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/static-files/) version recommends `{{STATIC_URL}}`

Comment: I see. I was trying to find a bug that caused most of my templates to load my stylesheet except one page. I changed it over to `static` method instead of `STATIC_URL` method, and the bug was gone. Good call on the suggestions based on versions.

Comment: But as I just tried and found out that I can set `STATIC_URL = '/static/abcd/'`, basically just an arbitrary path and Django still correctly fetches static files. For example, it is serving a CSS file from `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/abcd/css/app.css" type="text/css">` as seen in the DevTools although there is no such directory on my system. My CSS file is in `common_static/css/app.css` and is collected to `static/css/app.css`. So this threw a really big wrench into my understanding of how STATIC_URL works. How is this possible?

Comment: @RusI `STATIC_URL` is the url Django creates, it is not a directory.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but it still has to point to en existing resource, right? In my case it's pointing to an invalid resource but it still works.

Comment: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/abcd/css/app.css" type="text/css">` will actually render with domain name appended, like `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.example.com/static/abcd/css/app.css" type="text/css">`. you must ensure the file is served in `https://www.example.com/static/abcd/css/app.css`

Answer (score 43):

`STATICFILES_DIRS`: You can keep the static files for your project here e.g. the ones used by your templates.

`STATIC_ROOT`: leave this empty, when you do `manage.py collectstatic`, it will search for all the static files on your system and move them here. Your static file server is supposed to be mapped to this folder wherever it is located. Check it after running collectstatic and you'll find the directory structure django has built.

--------Edit----------------

As pointed out by @DarkCygnus, STATIC_ROOT should point at a directory on your filesystem, the folder should be empty since it will be populated by Django.

> `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`

or

> `STATIC_ROOT = '/opt/web/project/static_files'`

--------End Edit -----------------

`STATIC_URL`: '/static/' is usually fine, it's just a prefix for static files.

Comment: Here, the link to static file management in 1.3 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/static-files/

Comment: `STATICFILES_DIRS` should serve as additional dirs for static files.If you put all your css/js/images into the APP_NAME/static/APP_NAME folder,then there is no need to specify `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, about the leaving empty the STATIC_ROOT, I actually had to specify it in `settings.py` (by doing `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')`) before running the collectstatic command.

Comment: Hmm, I can see how easily this can be misleading. What I mean by leaving it empty is that is usually starts out empty, no files in it. I will update the answer to remove the confusion.

Answer (score 11):

### Aug, 2023 Update:

First of all, I explain about [STATIC_ROOT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#static-root), then [STATIC_URL[2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#static-url).

### <STATIC_ROOT>

`STATIC_ROOT` can set a folder path and be used with the command below which collects the static files of the apps and admin in a Django project into the folder path. *`STATIC_ROOT` never ever influence to `STATIC_URL`:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

And `STATIC_ROOT` only works in Production Mode which is [DEBUG = False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#debug) as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DEBUG = False // Production Mode
```

Now, we have a django project with the static files `core.js` in `core` folder where `settings.py` is and `myapp.css` in `myapp` folder which is **an app** as shown below:

[image]

And `css`, `fonts`, `img` and `js` folders in `admin` folder in `venv` folder as shown below. *I use the virtual environment named `venv` for this django project so the static files for admin is in it and the relative path to `admin` folder is `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/`:

[image]

Then, we set `BASE_DIR / 'static/'` which is `C:\Users\kai\django-project\static` on Windows in my case to `STATIC_ROOT`. In addition, we set `DEBUG = False` because `STATIC_ROOT` only works in **Production Mode** as I said before:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DEBUG = False // Production Mode

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/' # Here
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

Now, we run the command below:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then, `static` folder is created and `css`, `fonts`, `img` and `js` folders in `admin` folder** and `myapp.css` in `myapp` folder are collected into `static` folder as shown below but as we can see, `core.js` in `core` folder is not collected into `static` folder as shown below because as I said before, the command `python manage.py collectstatic` collects static files from the apps and admin in a django project but `core` folder which has `settings.py` is not an app and admin. That's why `core.js` in `core` folder is not collected into `static` folder:

[image]

But, there is a way to collect `core.js` in `core` folder into `static` folder. To do that, we need to set `BASE_DIR / 'core/static/'` which is `C:\Users\kai\django-project\core\static` on Windows in my case to [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DEBUG = False

STATICFILES_DIRS = [ # Here
    BASE_DIR / 'core/static/'
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
```

Or, we need to set `core` to [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#installed-apps) in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DEBUG = False

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'core', # Here
]
```

Now again, we run the command below:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Then, input `yes` then press **Enter** to overwrite the existing `static` folder:

> You have requested to collect static files at the destination location
> as specified in your settings:
>
> C:\Users\kai\django-project\static
>
> This will overwrite existing files! Are you sure you want to do this?
>
> Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes

Now, `core.js` in `core` folder is collected into `static` folder as shown below:

[image]

### <STATIC_URL>

Next, I explain about `STATIC_URL`.

`STATIC_URL` can set the front directory part of static file URL between the host part and the file part of static file URL as shown below. *`STATIC_URL` never ever influence `STATIC_ROOT`:

```
       |     Host      |   Directory    |  File  |
       |               |Front |  Back   |        |
        <-------------> <----> <-------> <------>      
https://www.example.com/static/admin/css/base.css
```

For example, we set `'static/'` to `STATIC_URL` in `settings.py` as shown below. *`STATIC_URL` works in both **Development Mode** which is `DEBUG = True` and **Production Mode** which is `DEBUG = False`:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DEBUG = False

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'core/static/'
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'
STATIC_URL = 'static/' # Here
```

Then, open Django Admin:

[image]

Then, press **F12** to open **Developer Tools** to check the resources used for the currently opened Django Admin page from **Sources** and there are the static files for admin which we have just collected into `static` folder:

[image]

Then, hover `base.css` in `css` to check the URL:

[image]

As we can see, we could set the front directory part `static`:

```
                       Here  
                     <------>
http://localhost:8000/static/admin/css/base.css
```

And, this URL below is in this case of `www.example.com` with `https`:

```
                         Here
    　　　　　　　　　　　<------>
https://www.example.com/static/admin/css/base.css
```

And, we can change the front directory part `static` to `hello/world`.

So, just change `STATIC_URL` from `'static/'` to `'hello/world/'` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

DEBUG = False

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'core/static/'
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'
STATIC_URL = 'hello/world/' # Here
```

Then, refresh the Django Admin page:

[image]

Then, the front directory part `static` is changed to `hello/world` as shown below:

```
                         Here  
                     <----------->
http://localhost:8000/hello/world/admin/css/base.css
```

Answer (score 3):

All the answers above are helpful but none solved my issue. In my production file, my STATIC_URL was `https://<URL>/static` and I used the same STATIC_URL in my dev settings.py file.

This causes a silent failure in  django/conf/urls/static.py.

The test `elif not settings.DEBUG or '://' in prefix:` 
picks up the '//' in the URL and does not add the static URL pattern, causing no static files to be found.

It would be thoughtful if Django spit out an error message stating you can't use a `http(s)://` with `DEBUG = True`

I had to change STATIC_URL to be '/static/'

Answer (score 0):

After **Django 3.1+**, There is a slight change in the configuration of the directory paths, but the concepts are the same, of course.

### STATICFILES_DIRS

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    BASE_DIR / 'app_1/static',
    BASE_DIR / 'app_2/static',
]
```

As the name suggests, it is a list of directories. It is used for specifying more than one directory for static files. Most useful for the sake of the reusability of an app. Instead of having one directory for all the static files, each app has its independent directory. Just like templates for each individual app.

To configure static files directory of an app:

```
=> my_app
    => static
        => my_app
            => css
            => js
```

In development mode, with the command `python manage.py runserver`, Django searches for static files using the `STATICFILES_FINDERS` setting. By default, it tries to find the requested static file in folders listed in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting. In case of failure, Django tries to find the file using `django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder`, which looks in the static folder of every installed application in the project.

### STATIC_ROOT

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
```

It is the absolute path to the directory where `python manage.py collectstatic` will collect static files for deployment. Example:

```
/var/www/example.com/static/"
```

For development, it is not necessary to configure `STATIC_ROOT`, but extremely important for production. This is the path to be considered by the Nginx, Apache servers to access the website's static files.

### STATIC_URL

URL to use when referring to static files located in STATIC_ROOT. Example: "static/" or "http://static.example.com/"

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Now, suppose I decide to configure the `STATIC_URL='/asset/'`, then I need to change `STATIC_ROOT=BASE_DIR / 'asset'` and the name of my directory should also be `asset`.

Reference:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/