# Importing Static files to template with Django

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-staticfiles

I'm having trouble loading my CSS file into my HTML template. Below are the invovled files I'm working with. Can anyone see why the CSS wouldn't be loading?

**settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

**words.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'hello/words.css' %}" />
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^
    url(r'^Words', hello.views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^db', hello.views.db, name='db'),
    url(r'^Add', hello.views.create, name='create'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

**words.css**

```
 .pri {
     color: blue;
 }, hello.views.index, name='index'),
```

***Project Structure***

```
murmurwall/
├── Procfile
├── README.md
├── hello
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── forms.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── management
│   │   └── commands
│   │       ├── CSV
│   │       │   └── Pretty\ Little\ Liars.csv
│   │       ├── __pycache__
│   │       │   └── update_words.cpython-34.pyc
│   │       └── update_words.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   └── hello
│   │       └── words.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── add_word.html
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── db.html
│   │   └── words.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── manage.py
├── murmurwall
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-34.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-34.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   └── humans.txt
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── requirements.txt
├── runtime.txt
└── staticfiles
    ├── admin
    │   ├── css
    │   │   ├── base.css
    │   │   ├── changelists.css
    │   │   ├── dashboard.css
    │   │   ├── forms.css
    │   │   ├── ie.css
    │   │   ├── login.css
    │   │   ├── rtl.css
    │   │   └── widgets.css
    │   ├── img
    │   │   ├── changelist-bg.gif
    │   │   ├── changelist-bg_rtl.gif
    │   │   ├── default-bg-reverse.gif
    │   │   ├── default-bg.gif
    │   │   ├── deleted-overlay.gif
    │   │   ├── gis
    │   │   │   ├── move_vertex_off.png
    │   │   │   └── move_vertex_on.png
    │   │   ├── icon-no.gif
    │   │   ├── icon-unknown.gif
    │   │   ├── icon-yes.gif
    │   │   ├── icon_addlink.gif
    │   │   ├── icon_alert.gif
    │   │   ├── icon_calendar.gif
    │   │   ├── icon_changelink.gif
    │   │   ├── icon_clock.gif
    │   │   ├── icon_deletelink.gif
    │   │   ├── icon_error.gif
    │   │   ├── icon_searchbox.png
    │   │   ├── icon_success.gif
    │   │   ├── inline-delete-8bit.png
    │   │   ├── inline-delete.png
    │   │   ├── inline-restore-8bit.png
    │   │   ├── inline-restore.png
    │   │   ├── inline-splitter-bg.gif
    │   │   ├── nav-bg-grabber.gif
    │   │   ├── nav-bg-reverse.gif
    │   │   ├── nav-bg-selected.gif
    │   │   ├── nav-bg.gif
    │   │   ├── selector-icons.gif
    │   │   ├── selector-search.gif
    │   │   ├── sorting-icons.gif
    │   │   ├── tooltag-add.png
    │   │   └── tooltag-arrowright.png
    │   └── js
    │       ├── LICENSE-JQUERY.txt
    │       ├── SelectBox.js
    │       ├── SelectFilter2.js
    │       ├── actions.js
    │       ├── actions.min.js
    │       ├── admin
    │       │   ├── DateTimeShortcuts.js
    │       │   └── RelatedObjectLookups.js
    │       ├── calendar.js
    │       ├── collapse.js
    │       ├── collapse.min.js
    │       ├── core.js
    │       ├── inlines.js
    │       ├── inlines.min.js
    │       ├── jquery.init.js
    │       ├── jquery.js
    │       ├── jquery.min.js
    │       ├── prepopulate.js
    │       ├── prepopulate.min.js
    │       ├── timeparse.js
    │       └── urlify.js
    ├── hello
    │   └── words.css
    └── humans.txt
```

Comment: `href="{% static 'hello/words.css' %}"`, hello should be a folder where your words.css is. And also, show us your file structure.

Comment: did u checked css in your html page itself. whether it is working fine there

Comment: posted the project structure

Answer (score 0):

Your  `STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'` need to be the absolute path to the static files. For example `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_URL.strip("/"))`. This might have to be changed for deployment. An example i use for openshift:

`if 'OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR' in os.environ:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR'), 'wsgi', 'static')
else:
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, STATIC_URL.strip("/"))`

See also [django static static url static root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687927/django-static-static-url-static-root)

Comment: I changed my STATIC_ROOT to os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL.strip("/")), didn't seem to do the trick. :(

Comment: can you post the full folder structure off your app?

Comment: posted the project structure

Comment: look in the rendered html source where the css link goes to see where it is looking for it. It should also give a 404 output on the manage.py runserver.

Comment: nothing css related gets added to the rendered HTML when I view it in browser. it also doesn't throw a 404........