# Why do I need to define both STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS?

Tags: django, deployment, django-staticfiles, static-files

If I define only one, the page displays without any CSS/JS. If I define both, the pages load fine. Why is that? I thought STATICFILES_DIRS is extraneous?

There's an answer here but it doesn't answer why I need both. It simply says what both does, which in my eyes is the same thing. What's the difference?

[List of definitions for STATIC/STATIC_ROOT/STATICFILES_DIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687927/django-static-static-url-static-root)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have scoured on StackOverflow, I think I can sum it up as follows:

STATIC_ROOT is referenced as the static server, be it the default Django static server or the static server made on Heroku/etc. You point to this in urls.py

STATICFILES_DIR is referencing the stuff within static assets so if there are separate folders, one for CSS, one for JS, etc.

Feel free to add!

Answer (score 1):

STATICFILES_DIRS is extraneous. You only need to use it if you are using a static files directory outside of the static files directories inside of your apps. Without seeing more of your code, and the structure of your project I can't even begin to guess why your pages aren't loading, but you definitely do not need to specify a STATICFILES_DIRS.