# Change Static Root Directory and Uploading in Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-settings, django-uploads

I am following 2 different tutorials on creating a Django App. In one video (on lynda) it states that my static (javascript/css/image) files should live here:

```
project_name/project_name/static/
```

I have a js and css file in there and it links up to my templates just fine. In the second tutorial on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YH-ipgxlJzs&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzQFqfCur9CJ4QnKQTVXUsRy&index=25) (1:38 mark), I am learning how to store uploaded files. After using the `collectstatic` command, ALL of my files are now going to

```
project_name/static/
```

my settings.py:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATIC_URL = '/static/'    
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "/the_office/the_office/static")
```

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022558/differences-between-staticfiles-dir-static-root-and-media-root) for a better understanding of static_root vs static files_dir and I'd rather it stay where it originally was. I've tried all combinations of file paths I could think of messing around with `Static_Root` and `StaticFiles_Dirs`but no luck. How can I change the path back to the original? Any further clarification of the `os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` is appreciated as well.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687927/django-static-static-url-static-root

Comment: @rnevius I saw the first link already but did not see the second one. After a 2nd hard look, the link made much more sense to me (rather than my initial 1st skim). Thank you for bringing them both to my attention.

Comment: I am hoping to however get an answer for better understanding of the os.path syntax.