# What is the need of providing STATIC_ROOT?

Tags: django

Can anyone explain to me the need of providing STATIC_ROOT in a django project? As it seems, 
Everything works fine if I just declare the STATICFILES_DIRS and not STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18628930/

Comment: Note if you just put your static files inside _static/_ directories inside your apps, you don't even need to define STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: Then why are we even doing these if we don't need them in our project?

Comment: @aNoNyMoUs there is cases that static files folder outside the django project folder, then only you need to define `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`STATIC_ROOT` is only needed in production, since the Django development server `runserver` takes care of serving static files directly from your static directories.

`STATIC_ROOT` is the absolute path to the directory where `python manage.py collectstatic` will collect static files for deployment.

Example: `STATIC_ROOT="/var/www/example.com/static/"`

Now the command `python manage.py collectstatic` will copy all the static files(ie in static folder in your apps, static files in all paths) to the directory `/var/www/example.com/static/`. now you only need to serve this directory on apache or nginx..etc.

Note: You often see examples where `STATIC_ROOT` is set to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')`. This is a **bad** practice as it creates the static folder inside your source code repository. Always set it to a path **outside** of your project folder, e.g. `/var/www/example.com/static/` when your project is in `/var/www/example.com/src/`.

Answer (score 0):

when you change DEBUG in settings.py to False on your production server, if you not using STATIC_ROOT, the files on the page will not be shown. And yes, you must do `collectstatic` as it was written in the previous answer

Comment: Also, when we refer static files in our html, are we referring the file from the dir that got created from doing createstatic or the source dir which was used in createstatic?