# I don't really understand how STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT Django settings works

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I have some troubles understanding how static files works on Django 3.0.7

In my `settings.py` file, I wrote this:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join('static')
```

Here is what I understood. So correct me if I'm wrong. This is the whole point of my question.

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

This one is quite self explanatory. It's the URL root to the static files.
This way I can reach my `picture.jpg` in my `/static/` folder via my browser by typing the `http://<ip-or-domain>/static/picture.jpg`.

But I have some troubles with the two others.

```py
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),)
```

This parameter tells Django I want to use all the folders called `static` as static folder where Django will collect every file to put them in the main static folder with the command `python3 manage.py collectstatic`. The first argument gives the root where Django should start searching and the second argument is the name of the folder which be identified as app static folder.

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join('static')
```

And this parameter is the one which indicate the path of the main static folder where the collected static files will be put.

Am I right until now ?

So here is my issue.
When I launch my server, I got this error on my development server, which I don't on my production server:

> ERRORS:
>
> ?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.

So this is logic, because the `STATICFILES_DIRS` includes the main static folder (at the root of my project). And this one cannot be collected in order to put the files into it again.

But if I remove `STATICFILES_DIRS`, Django won't be able to collect the files from each app.
If I remove `STATIC_ROOT`, all my static files won't be usable by my app once the `collectstatic` done.

What is the problem and can I solve it ? Did I misunderstood something ?

Must I rename my main static folder with another name ? This is quite a strange solution because I saw a lot of Django projects where they still use `static` as name for their main static folder as well as the app static folders.

Thank you for helping a Django noob anyway. I read a lot of similar questions on Stackoverflow but I still don't understand where I'm wrong.

FYI:

```
Django 3.0.7
Python 3.7
(dev) Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
(prod) Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

choose them seperately

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),) #no slash

STATICFILES_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_cdn")
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8690002/1388866 Read this.

Comment: What do you mean by that ? Giving my STATICFILES_ROOT a different name than 'static' ?
And yes, there are no slash in it. It's a typo I made when I wrote the question. I will edit that.

Comment: Django will collect the files in different folder .

Comment: i think I got it because of your link. Thank you.