# body { background: rgba(240, 234, 234, 0.897) url("images/background.gif") no-repeat; }

Tags: django

Template code

```html
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'polls/style.css' %}">

{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

CSS code

```
li a {
    color: rgb(13, 238, 43);
}
body {
    background: rgba(240, 234, 234, 0.897) url("images/background.gif") no-repeat;
}
```

There is an background.gif in polls/static/images/background.gif

Except the background image, all the styles are presented correctly in the browser.

What might be the reasons? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The url() CSS function is used to include a file. The parameter is an
> absolute URL, a **relative URL**, or a data URI

In your settings define `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`, then `url('/static/images/background.gif')` will probably work or you can use `url('{{ STATIC_URL }}images/background.git`, note: no backslash after `{{STATIC_URL}}`

Read more here [**Difference between `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8687927/difference-between-static-static-url-and-static-root-on-django#:%7E:text=STATICFILES_DIRS%20%3A%20You%20can%20keep%20the,system%20and%20move%20them%20here.)